# Probability question from the real life-dont know how to calculate

Tags: probability

I would appreciate if you could help me calculate (and maybe explain if it's not too hard) a probabilty question I have from the real life:

A plane has 266 seats (plus 18 in business).
The seating is a 2-4-2 configuration: a-b, c-d-e-f, ...
We were 6 people, 1 got seperated.
5 people got a,c,d,e,f.
After the check-in, we found out the other friend of ours got the b!
(*He did not pay for a business ticket of course)

My question is, what is the probability of that to happen?
He did not ask for a specific seat, and I assume that it makes a difference if the plane was full (someone MUST seat there) or if there were some empty seats.

I feel that calculating 1/261 is too simple and I should maybe take into account more variables.

Thank you very much!
Hope I've explained myself clearly enough :)

Oron

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to make a sensible answer.  How many people were traveling together?  Clearly if the airline tries to keep people together, no group could have gotten the single seat.  So it makes a big difference if there are a lot of unassigned single travelers.  Just for example.

Comment: The critical piece of data is how many "other friends" are on the plane.  If you are returning from a holiday where you made lots of friends, the probability is quite high.

Comment: Sometimes when I buy flights I can choose the seats right on the spot and they will be assigned during check-in. Maybe this is what happened?

Comment: Thank you all - please assume that this is the only person we were hoping will seat there, no other "friends" were on this trip. Also, no seat was choosen prior to the check in, everything was at the spot.  Regarding the airline, lets assume that every other person was an individual, and was flying by himself and no groups, just to simplify everything

Comment: As others have indicated, I agree with you that $1/261$ is too simple, but there's just too much we don't know.  For example, when a single passenger arrives, it might be the airline's policy to try to assign him to a row that already has $5$ seats assigned, in order to be able to better accommodate future arrivals traveling in groups.

Comment: Thank yoy for your comment. Please see my other comment and lets assume that everyone else got a single, random seat, with no regards to the airline or groups or anythong else.  I know I said "real world" but I guess I need to simplify my data since this is very complicated for the reallife answer